# Gilmore-Lawler lower bound

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, graph-algorithm

Does anyone know how to implement or where can I find an implementation of Gilmore-Lawler lower bound for Quadratic Assignment Problem? 
I've read several mathematics papers and the idea is to convert the QAP into a LAP combining the two matrices of the original problem. But how can I implement it? The only hint that my teacher gave me is "Gilmore-Lawler" and anything else.
I need it for a group project and I'm totally lost.

Thanks.